# bootstrap put search form to right

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap

I make a search form by bootstrap, it is on left, but I want to put the form to right. How to make it?

[image]

code:

```
<%= form_tag search_path, method: :get, class: "form-inline col-sm-4" do %>
  <div class="form-group">
     <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search], class: "form-control", placeholder: "Search for..."%>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= submit_tag "Search", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: use class `pull-right`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use `class="pull-right"` class like:

```
<div class="pull-right">
 <%= form_tag search_path, method: :get, class: "form-inline col-sm-4" do %>
  <div class="form-group">
   <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search], class: "form-control", placeholder: "Search for..."%>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
  <%= submit_tag "Search", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
  </div>
 <% end %>
</div>
```

Comment: If the answer was useful to you, then accept it. This way you help those who helped you, @pangpang.